# One Common Class to Store Objects of All Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, object

I have a windows Forms project with 8 forms. Everytime I open a new Form I do this:

```
new FormX().Show();
this.Hide();
```

Due to this, I realized I am creating Multiple objects of Same form while it's previous copies exist, i.e if once i opened FormX and then I hid it and called next Form. When my work was done with it and I had to go back to FormX, I created the object once again. I do not want to do this as this consumes memory and makes application slow.

I want to know if there is a way to store all the objects of all forms in one class/form like this:

```
Form1 obj1=new Form1();
Form2 obj2=new Form2();
```

and everytime i need to make one of them visible I simply write obj1.show() or obj2.show()

Is it possible to store these objects in Program.cs class?

Comment: You may use a public static List of Forms.

Comment: Will you be satisfied (taking in account time spend writing this question) with the answer `"Yes"`? If not, add more details: what is the problem, what doesn't works, expected behavior, etc.

Comment: Problem:
1) Too many objects created for one form in turn leading to multiple copies of the form available but hidden. I want only one copy of form available at all time.
2) Too much memory consumed in duplicat forms. I dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is somewhat vague. But based on what you seem to be asking, you have a couple of options in addition to the one you propose:

1. Don't try to reuse the form. Instead of calling `Hide()` just call `Close()`.
2. Implement each `Form` class as a singleton. Then make sure you *don't* close each form (i.e. continue to call `Hide()` instead), and access the relevant instance from the static instance property.

Example of #2:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Form1> _instance = new Lazy<Form1>(() => new Form1());
    public static Form1 Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
}
```

then elsewhere…

```
Form1.Instance.Show();
// ... do some stuff with Form1
Form1.Instance.Hide();
```